# Visits don't count while logged in on mobile

Tags: bug, mobile-web, consecutive-days, visited-days

I noticed on my profile that I have [2 consecutive days](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1553081/) visited currently. I know that I haven't missed a day (was going for that consecutive badge because why not), and the day that didn't count was a day that I only accessed the website on mobile. I did click around on SO, to my profile page and some questions pages, so there was definitely normal activity there.

The reason that my [meta profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/193130/) does have a consecutive streak going is because I selected to view the desktop version on meta at some point and that is still happening. I completed the same activities on meta (clicking through to my profile + to questions) that I did on the main SO.

Comment: It could be that you were logged in to MSO, and not on SO. Did you perform any actions on that day? Check your activity or votes tab.

Comment: Are you talking about accessing the website from a mobile device (which should work fine and register site accesses as if you were on a desktop) or using the still-in-alpha Android app (which probably works fine but might have bugs)?

Comment: Not the app, just a mobile device on the web browser.

Comment: I accessed every day on Android web browser for a week and my streak remains safe

Answer (score 1):

If you open up a private browsing window (to start a "fresh" session as you'd have on a mobile), and log in, you will notice that you aren't automatically logged in to all other sites on the network. Even if you manually go to meta.stackoverflow.com in the same window when you've already logged in to stackoverflow.com, you won't start out logged in.

Chances are that you were logged on to only one portion of the site, and were browsing thinking you were logged in when you actually weren't. This could cause the frustration you're having.

Also note that when you're on a mobile, your IP address often changes frequently, and the SO powers that be will frequently log you out. So if you log back in you may think you are logged in to previous sites, but because of the different IP you may need to re-login to the other sites on the network again as well.

Comment: IP changing shouldn't log you out...very likely he just wasn't logged in at all.  We don't enable global auth on mobile due to the extra HTTP request it requires.

Comment: I get constantly logged out of mobile it seems. I don't know why, but it seems like whenever I change from my wi-fi to 3g, or from 3g to another wi-fi, I have to login again. If IP changing doesn't log you out, then what's doing it?

Comment: @jmac just to follow up - I *never* get automatically logged out via mobile despite jumping from Wi-Fi to 3G/4G frequently.  I'd hazard a guess it is something on your end, but no idea what

Comment: @psubsee2003 It just happened to me again. Checked the site on 3g on the way home from work -- was logged in read this thread fine (and saw my notifications). Got home, on wi-fi, connected to the Workplace, was disconnected (even though I had been logged in on the train). Logged in, got a notification here, and visited. Not logged in even though I had on the Workplace. Definitely may be the same issue for the poster (though I don't know what causes it)